# Am I misusing this Windows registry parsing tool (yarp)? Getting error Invalid signature: b'\\xff\\xfeW\\x00'

Tags: python, registry, computer-forensics

New to forensics, but we're thinking in order to pull registries from many machines for baseline analysis, we would use PowerShell to run:

`reg export HKLM hklm.reg`

on every machine and then parse the exported `hklm.reg` files (same with HKCU, etc).

Seemed simple enough, so I tried using [`yarp`](https://github.com/msuhanov/yarp) to parse it like:

```
from yarp import *

# A primary file is specified here.
primary_path = './data/registry/hklm.reg'

# Open the primary file and each transaction log file discovered.
primary_file = open(primary_path, 'rb')

# Open the hive and recover it, if required.
hive = Registry.RegistryHive(primary_file)
```

and got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BaseBlockException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_28960\903824968.py in <module>
      9 
     10 # Open the hive and recover it, if required.
---> 11 hive = Registry.RegistryHive(primary_file)
     12 
     13 '''

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\yarp\Registry.py in __init__(self, file_object, tolerate_minor_errors)
    205 
    206         def __init__(self, file_object, tolerate_minor_errors = True):
--> 207                 self.registry_file = RegistryFile.PrimaryFile(file_object, tolerate_minor_errors)
    208                 self.tolerate_minor_errors = tolerate_minor_errors
    209                 self.effective_slack = set()

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\yarp\RegistryFile.py in __init__(self, file_object, tolerate_minor_errors)
   1107                 self.last_sequence_number = None
   1108 
-> 1109                 self.baseblock = BaseBlock(self.file_object)
   1110                 if not self.baseblock.is_primary_file:
   1111                         raise NotSupportedException('Invalid file type')

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\yarp\RegistryFile.py in __init__(self, file_object, no_hive_bins)
    307                 signature = self.get_signature()
    308                 if signature != b'regf': # This is the only check possible before we validate the base block.
--> 309                         raise BaseBlockException('Invalid signature: {}'.format(signature))
    310 
    311                 # We have to trust these fields even if the base block is not valid. We can adjust these values later (according to the log file).

BaseBlockException: "Invalid signature: b'\\xff\\xfeW\\x00'"
```

Am I misusing the library? How else would I parse these exported registries (into python dictionaries or DataFrames)?

Answer (score 0):

From the owner of the repo:

> Hello.
>
> You are trying to use the library against a text file containing
> exported registry data. This is not supported.
>
> And such text files do not contain deleted data, as well as some
> important metadata for allocated keys and values. For analysis, a
> better option is "reg save  " (see:
> https://dfir.ru/2020/10/03/exporting-registry-hives-from-a-live-system/).

This was obviously the correct answer.